# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user [...] (using password: YES) Laravel 5.2 on Live Web Server

Tags: laravel-5, cpanel, live

I am trying to login on my website which is built in laravel 5.2 but I am getting this error of access denied for user on my live web server. I have also put credentials in .env file that are shown below:

```
APP_URL=http://lagaikhaiexchange.com
    
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=lagaikhaiexchange.com
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
    DB_USERNAME=myuser  
    DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

and I also gave the all privileges to user `lagaikha_cricketuser` But I am unable to find that why my application is not connecting to database. Although On localhost, the same code working fine and doing everything.
Any help would be appreciated... Thank you

Comment: I doubt anyone else can do much to prove whether or not you set up the privs correctly, without evidence of where/how you set them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected the problem. There was server problem that was using some default password.
and I change my password then restart and it works